# how to generate array based on 2 other arrays using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 lists length of n
the goal is to create a new list with certain order of elements based on 2 existing lists

input:

```
5
5 2 3 1 4
1 3 2 4 5
```

output:

```
4 3 2 5 1
```

My solution works, but it is too slow on big sets of data, like 100000 items in each list

```
n = int(input())
first = input().split()
second = input().split()

res = [first[second.index(digit)] for digit in first]

print(*res)
```

I'm trying to use numpy.fromfunction() to make it work faster, but getting error, can't figure out what am I doing wrong

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input())

first = np.fromstring(input(), sep=' ', dtype=int)
second = np.fromstring(input(), sep=' ', dtype=int)

print(np.fromfunction(lambda x: first[np.where(first == second[x])[0][0]], (n,), dtype=int))
```

Comment: `fromfunction` does not compile anything, so it is not a speed tool, even when it works.  For `(n,)`, all it does it does pass `np.arange(n)` to your `lambda`.  It isn't an iterator, fast or slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an index that maps the numbers to their positions:

```
n = int(input())
first = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
second = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

index = { v:n for n,v in enumerate(second) }

res = [first[index[i]] for i in first]

print(*res)
```

Output:

```
4 3 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is O(n^2). You can try to do in O(n):

```py
n = int(input())
first = input().split()
second = input().split()

second_dict = {}
for i, x in enumerate(second):
    second_dict[x] = i

first_i = [second_dict[x] for x in first]
res = [first[i] for i in first_i]

print('output:', *res)
```

prints:

```
3
a b c
c a b
output: b c a
```

Comment: I don't think you're solving the same problem.  The answer with your set of inputs should be "3 1 2", because "c" is in the 3rd position, "a" is in the 1st position, etc.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think what OP wants is `Find the index k of first[i] in second list, print first[k]` and that's what I did. May be I misunderstood? I am not sure if I did tho

Comment: Ah, I see.  I assumed he was printing the position numbers, not the corresponding list entries.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, you can index your `second` array using the indices of the sorted `first` array (sorted because the `first` array says where they should go, but we want to get the ordering of the indices that selects the correct terms from `second`).

```py
import numpy as np

first = np.fromstring(input(), sep=" ", dtype=int)
second = np.fromstring(input(), sep=" ", dtype=int)
res = second[np.argsort(first)]
print(res)
```

Input:

```py
5 2 3 1 4
1 3 2 4 5
```

Output:

```py
[4 3 2 5 1]
```

Comment: OP, is this what you are looking for? The other answers seem to say something different. I understood your question to mean that the `first` array gives the index where the value in the `second` array should be placed. So the first value in `first` being 5 means that the first value in `second` should be placed at index `5` (rather 4, since python is 0-indexed).

Comment: I'm originally searched for faster solution, the problem was in my algorithm, it was too time consuming. appeared the problem can be solved without numpy. neverthless, your solution works perfectly well, but testing system somehow doesn't want to accept it, may be it was forbidden to use numpy library

Comment: Are you sure it was giving the correct solution? I know it works for the example in the question because that example happens to have the same answer for both methods. The accepted answer provides different solutions when I test other inputs.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it works correctly, because I tested it on many sets of input data.
just changed `print(res)` to `print(*res)`

Answer (score 0):

Thx everyone for help, found another one solution

```
n = int(input())

first = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
second = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

res = [0]*n

for i in range(n):
    res[first[i]-1] = second[i]

print(*res)
```

Comment: Try testing this on `first = [3, 4, 0, 2, 1]` and `second = [2, 1, 3, 4, 0]`. Does this answer produce the desired result?